# url method of ImageField returns a non-Url value - Django

Tags: python, django, url, django-models

I'm developing using Django on Windows. I have a model with an imagefield, and use a form to fill it. Images get uploaded without problem. The problem occurs when I attempt to show an uploaded image inside a template by coding this:

```
<img src ='{{object.image.url}}'/>
```

(object is an instance of the relevant model, and image is the name of the image field)

However, the image is not displayed, as the url method returns not a URL but a path like this:

c:/pp/pm/static/image/xyz.png

What should I do to make it a real URL?

edit:

MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL settings are below:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/pp/pm/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Your code isn't showing.

Comment: Why don't you make it a relative path from what .url returns?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it up. Code is showing now.

Comment: I have added those settings to my question. Prior to posting, I read those examples, and in the example below the url method returns a url:
>>>car.photo.url
u'http://media.example.com/cars/chevy.jpg'

Comment: MEDIAL_URL should be a fully-specified URL, e.g. http://subdomain.example.com/static as shown in http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url

Comment: I also tried specifying a full path. I don't know why, but in my case the url method seems not to take MEDIA_URL into account.

Comment: @SilentGhost: docs doesn't say it has to be a fully qualified URL. In fact I have been, in all my projects, using a relative URL, '/media/' as my MEDIA_URL for a long time.

Comment: @SilentGhost: maybe your comment should be an Answer.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the ProductImage in a satchmo store.  The value being stored is a absolute system path C:/path/static/images/img.jpg and not a relative path like on a *nix box images/img.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. At model declaration, I changed "upload_to" argument value from absolute path to relative, this fixes the problem.